# Diretivas de compilação em BPL´s

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em Delphi XE7, rodando sobre um servidor Oracle, Windows Server 2012 R2.
Nosso sistema é modularizado em várias BPL´s.

Frequentemente ocorre o erro **External exception C0000006**, sendo que uma das soluções sugeridas em diversos sites, inclusive aqui no *SOpt* é adicionar as diretivas `IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP` na aplicação.
Mas isso não resolveu no cliente. Penso que talvez adicionar essas diretivas em todas as BPL´s do sistema possa ajudar ou quem sabe ser a solução, só que não consigo adicionar nas BPL´s.

Na hora de tentar compilar é exibido o erro:

> "E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP'".

Sei que esse problema ocorre por não ter a `Uses Windows` adicionada na BPL, mas aí é que está o ponto: Não consigo adicionar a uses necessária nas BPL´s.

**Como posso solucionar essa questão?**
*Ou se alguém souber alguma forma efetiva de solucionar esse problema abaixo (que está me deixando sem dormir)...*

> External exception C0000006

Answer (score -1):

As @Ondrej Kelle responded on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031583/image-file-net-run-from-swap-in-delphi-xe7

"Just include Winapi.Windows in your uses clause (this is where IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP is declared):"